# Can we extend a billing Google account to an another development based google account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-developers-console

I have a project in developement which is associated with an Google developer account for firebase crashlytics and push notification.I need to consume "Place API" which require billing enabled. My management have one another Google account which has billing enabled. Can they somehow extend/link that account to my development account?

I tried to look into this but could not find any solution other than linking that development account itself with billing